# Using pipe to pass integer values between parent and child

Tags: c, pipe

I'm a little confused on how to properly use pipe() to pass integer values between two processes.

In my program I first create a pipe, then I fork it. I assume I have "Two" pipes then?

From what I understand, this is my assignment. 
My parent goes through a for loop checking an integer value "i" for a certain operation, increases a count variable, and saves value into an array. After each check my parent should pass an integer value, "i" to my child through a pipe. My child then uses that integer value, does some check on the value, and should increase a count variable, and save the result in a [shared?] array. Eventually; the child should return it's final count to the parent, who then prints out the two counts, and the "Shared" array.

-> I'm not sure I need to have a shared array or to save the results at all. I may only need the counts - the homework was ambiguous and I'm awaiting a response from the professor. Also; can I even do a shared array between processes? It sounds like a start of some problem to me.

-> Here are my questions:
One; how do I use pipes for integers? I've only seen them for character arrays and previous answers don't seem to think this is possible or legal..? I'm not sure. There was no resolution that I could find on it.

-> How do I use a unidirectional pipe to pass integers to a child? And have the child return something? I'm not sure how I'm able to... differentiate between the two pipes. I do "know" [or think I know] that I have to close one unused portion of each pipe to avoid "Some vague problem".

Sorry for the dumb questions; I haven't been taught processes (aside from fork) or pipes (at all) yet in this class - so I'm not really sure where to start!

Heres parts of my code - it's not pretty and it doesn't work and I don't expect it to. It's more of a shell placeholder. Once I figure out how to use a pipe - I'd Probably make the code make sense.

```
int main(void)
{
int fd[2];
pid_t childpid;
pid_t parentpid;
int i;
int threecount = 0;
int fivecount = 0;;
int results [MAXSIZE];

parentpid = getpid(); //Get current process ID number

pipe(fd);
childpid = fork(); 

if(childpid == 0){
close(fd[0]); //Closing this for some other reason

}
int j = 0;

if(childpid > 0)
close(fd[1]); //Closing this for some reason


if( childpid == -1 )
{
    perror("Failed to fork\n");
    return 1;
}
if (childpid > 0)
{
    for(i = 1; i < MAXSIZE;i++)
    {
        if(i % 5 == 0)
        {
            fivecount++;
            i = results[j];
            j++; 
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
}
else if (childpid == 0)
    {
        if(i % 3 == 0) //This i here should probably be the i value above, piped to the child
        {
            threecount++;
            i = results[j];  //This should be part of th pipe
            j++;    //Trying to keep count of that shared array, not really the right way to do it though.
        }

    }
    printf("%d  %d  \n", fivecount,threecount);
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: It will generally be easier for people to provide an answer if you have a more specific question, preferably with code that you've tried so far.

Comment: fyi: pipe() opens two descriptors; one outbound, one inbound. If your communication is one-way from child to parent (or parent to child) you will not need both. this is why the samples you've seen (and commented on here) close the unneeded descriptor in each process respectively.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is about as lame (and no error checking, btw) a sample as I can muster for using a pipe to send int from a parent to a child process, where the child was launched from fork(). It gets more complicated (obviously) for sending *and* receiving data, but i can't do *everything* for you. This just forks and waits for an int (actually, the number of bytes that are used by an int) from the child.

**Update:** Added send+response two-way communication example after this one. See the second code listing for more information.

Hope it helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd[2];
    int val = 0;

    // create pipe descriptors
    pipe(fd);

    // fork() returns 0 for child process, child-pid for parent process.
    if (fork() != 0)
    {
        // parent: writing only, so close read-descriptor.
        close(fd[0]);

        // send the value on the write-descriptor.
        val = 100;
        write(fd[1], &val, sizeof(val));
        printf("Parent(%d) send value: %d\n", getpid(), val);

        // close the write descriptor
        close(fd[1]);
    }
    else
    {   // child: reading only, so close the write-descriptor
        close(fd[1]);

        // now read the data (will block)
        read(fd[0], &val, sizeof(val));
        printf("Child(%d) received value: %d\n", getpid(), val);

        // close the read-descriptor
        close(fd[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Parent(5943) send value: 100
Child(5945) received value: 100
```

---

**Update:** Expanded to include send+response using two pipe sets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

// some macros to make the code more understandable
//  regarding which pipe to use to a read/write operation
//
//  Parent: reads from P1_READ, writes on P1_WRITE
//  Child:  reads from P2_READ, writes on P2_WRITE
#define P1_READ     0
#define P2_WRITE    1
#define P2_READ     2
#define P1_WRITE    3

// the total number of pipe *pairs* we need
#define NUM_PIPES   2

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd[2*NUM_PIPES];
    int val = 0, len, i;
    pid_t pid;

    // create all the descriptor pairs we need
    for (i=0; i<NUM_PIPES; ++i)
    {
        if (pipe(fd+(i*2)) < 0)
        {
            perror("Failed to allocate pipes");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    // fork() returns 0 for child process, child-pid for parent process.
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to fork process");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // if the pid is zero, this is the child process
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // Child. Start by closing descriptors we
        //  don't need in this process
        close(fd[P1_READ]);
        close(fd[P1_WRITE]);

        // used for output
        pid = getpid();

        // wait for parent to send us a value
        len = read(fd[P2_READ], &val, sizeof(val));
        if (len < 0)
        {
            perror("Child: Failed to read data from pipe");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (len == 0)
        {
            // not an error, but certainly unexpected
            fprintf(stderr, "Child: Read EOF from pipe");
        }
        else
        {
            // report what we received
            printf("Child(%d): Received %d\n", pid, val);

            // now double it and send it back
            val *= 2;

            printf("Child(%d): Sending %d back\n", pid, val);
            if (write(fd[P2_WRITE], &val, sizeof(val)) < 0)
            {
                perror("Child: Failed to write response value");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        // finished. close remaining descriptors.
        close(fd[P2_READ]);
        close(fd[P2_WRITE]);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    // Parent. close unneeded descriptors
    close(fd[P2_READ]);
    close(fd[P2_WRITE]);

    // used for output
    pid = getpid();

    // send a value to the child
    val = 42;
    printf("Parent(%d): Sending %d to child\n", pid, val);
    if (write(fd[P1_WRITE], &val, sizeof(val)) != sizeof(val))
    {
        perror("Parent: Failed to send value to child ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // now wait for a response
    len = read(fd[P1_READ], &val, sizeof(val));
    if (len < 0)
    {
        perror("Parent: failed to read value from pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (len == 0)
    {
        // not an error, but certainly unexpected
        fprintf(stderr, "Parent(%d): Read EOF from pipe", pid);
    }
    else
    {
        // report what we received
        printf("Parent(%d): Received %d\n", pid, val);
    }

    // close down remaining descriptors
    close(fd[P1_READ]);
    close(fd[P1_WRITE]);

    // wait for child termination
    wait(NULL);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

(compile with, e.g., `gcc thisfile.c -o test`)

**Output**

```
Parent(2794): Sending 42 to child
Child(2797): Received 42
Child(2797): Sending 84 back
Parent(2794): Received 84
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That's exactly what I need to get started!

Comment: this explaination is by far the easiest and most comprehensive for a noob struggling with OS assignment. Thank you dear sir.