# Communicating between child and parent processes using pipes

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe, parent-child

I am currently working on pipes and using pipes to make a child and parent process communicate with each other. I have it now for it to send a message to the child but I don't know how to make the child process respond to it. Not sure how I would do it and if anyone could find a webpage that is good for learning pipes in general, please link it if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For two-way communication you basically want to have 2 sets of pipes.

Please find more detailled information in:

- glibc manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipes-and-FIFOs.html#Pipes-and-FIFOs
- [Using pipe to pass integer values between parent and child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864265/using-pipe-to-pass-integer-values-between-parent-and-child)

  - the second example of the approved answer shows two-way communication you are looking for
- of course `man 2 pipe` and `man fork` as well

Comment: Is there any way you can show me code with 2 sets of pipes? I can't seem to understand what I need to do here.

Comment: @JamesWilliams Please have a look at the second example in the accepted answer - there is an example of a two-way communication using two pipe tuples.